# ffmpeg lags when streaming video+audio from RPi Zero W with Logitech C920

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, video-streaming, h.264, audio-streaming

I've been trying to setup a baby monitor with a Raspberry Pi Zero and a Logitech C920 webcam. It does work with VLC (cvlc) but it lags too much and gets worse over time.

So I am playing around with ffmpeg and I am getting some better results. This is what I've done so far.

First I set the webcam to output h264 1080p natively (the Pi Zero W can't afford to do any transcoding).

```
v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=1920,height=1080,pixelformat=1
```

Now, if I stream audio only with

```
ffmpeg \
-f alsa \
-i hw:1,0 \
-vn \
-flags +global_header \
-acodec aac \
-ac 1 \
-ar 16000 \
-ab 16k \
-f rtp rtp://192.168.0.10:5002 > audio.sdp
```

It works great and the lag is about 1 second (definitely acceptable).

If I stream video only with

```
ffmpeg \
-f v4l2 \
-vcodec h264 \
-i /dev/video0 \
-an \
-vcodec copy \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-r 30 \
-b:v 512k \
-flags +global_header \
-f rtp rtp://192.168.0.10:5000 > video.sdp
```

Same result, very little lag (for some reason the first -vcodec is necessary to force the webcam to output h264).

However, when I stream both with

```
ffmpeg \
-f v4l2 \
-vcodec h264 \
-i /dev/video0 \
-f alsa \
-i hw:1,0 \
-an \
-preset ultrafast \
-tune zerolatency \
-vcodec copy \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-r 30 \
-b:v 512k \
-flags +global_header \
-f rtp rtp://192.168.0.10:5000 \
-vn \
-flags +global_header \
-acodec aac \
-ac 1 \
-ar 16000 \
-ab 16k \
-f rtp rtp://192.168.0.10:5002 > both.sdp
```

The lag ramps up to ~10 seconds and audio and video are out of sync. Does anybody know why?

I've tried UDP and TCP instead of RTP but then the lag is **always** high, even with audio/video only.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

P.S. On the client side (MacOS) I'm receiving with

```
ffplay -protocol_whitelist file,rtp,udp -i file.sdp
```